# How does one delete a solution using the CRM SDK?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Apologies if this is blindingly obvious, but I can't find info on how to do a deletion of a solution from an organisation via the SDK.

I've already done imports sucessfully, using an ImportSolutionRequest object, but can't find the equivalent thing for deleting solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS has a guide up on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509050.aspx)

From that link

```
using (_serviceProxy = ServerConnection.GetOrganizationProxy(serverConfig))
{
    // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
    _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

    // Delete a solution
    QueryExpression queryImportedSolution = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = Solution.EntityLogicalName,
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "solutionid", "friendlyname" }),
        Criteria = new FilterExpression()
    };
    queryImportedSolution.Criteria.AddCondition("uniquename", ConditionOperator.Equal, ImportedSolutionName);
    Solution ImportedSolution = (Solution)_serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(queryImportedSolution).Entities[0];
    _serviceProxy.Delete(Solution.EntityLogicalName, (Guid)ImportedSolution.SolutionId);
}
```